# Check multiple login from different browser?

Tags: java

I am trying to write the java code that track the username that has been used to login the system from different machines. I couldnot figure out how to do it. I search the internet but couldn't get the right answer. Please provide me some hints or suggestion??

Comment: When someone logs in, write their IP address and login name to a file.  Read the file later to see how many logins for each name come from more than 3 IP addresses.  Those login names are your suspects.  Some ISP's rotate their IP addresses, so you have to see if the multiple IP addresses are in the same family.  Good luck.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc What do you mean in the same family?

Comment: My public IP address is 4.31.11.2.  4.31 or 4.31.11 would be the family, depending on the class of my ISP.

Comment: can you explain further? is this a web application or a standalone..

Comment: There is no accurate way to get the users ip address

Comment: i am trying it for standalone

Comment: check out this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/

Comment: For now it will be standalone or console but should be reusable code that means same code should be work if i try ti implement the project in future

Comment: You can easily achieve that using Spring security with a few configurations in your project. Check the Spring Security docs @ https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html under Concurrency Control segment.